# Switch statement indentation

Tags: switch-statement

Just out of curiosity, I was wondering why the indentantation on switch statements are the way they are. I'd expect that **break;** should be written on the same column as **case:** like we do with curly brackets on an if statement.

So why do we do it like this:

```
case 1: 
    //do stuff
    break;

case 2:
case 3:
    //do stuff
    break;
```

And not like this:

```
case 1:
    //do stuff
break;

case 2:
case 3:
    //do stuff
break;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference in either of those two ways of writing switch statements. If I wanted I could also write a switch statement like this

```
case 1: /*do stuff*/ break;case 3: case 2: /*do stuff*/ break;
```

The whitespaces you add will not be read by the compiler.
We add the spaces and the indentation so as to make our code easily readable to others.

In 4 words: no blocks, no indentation.

Cases are not opening a block. In C or C++ you can even put variables declarations (but the initializers are not called, except for static variables, that's a pitfall) at the beginning of the switch block.

Hence, as cases are just labels, indenting them does not seem that intuitive, and not indenting is the style chosen by most styles.

Comment: I do know this, my question is not an issue but more out of curiousity why the indentation standard for this is the way it is.
Therefore my question goes on, because your example can be translated to 
**if($i =1){ /*do stuff*/ } if ($i = 2){ /*do stuff*/ }**
The if statement's breaking character } is written on the same column as the starting phrase, while this is not the case with a switch statement.

Comment: The cases are logically labels. Many people put labels at the same indentation level as the block they are in. In my opinion, that way it's easier to read through the text.

I compare it with a timeline you can scroll through. You have markers on the time line itself, not indented into the content. You can then quickly point out where labels/markers are, without moving your eye away from the base-line.


I hope I can satisfy your curiosity. If you want we can continue talking about this I am quite enjoying this.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer, the label/timeline expample has put me to think. 
I guess **break;** should be interpreted as a local **exit();** or **die();** to 'exit' the switch program instead of only the case.

Comment: It would be correct to interpret break; as a local exit(); or return; for the particular case/cases. A break; statement doesn't let you get out of the switch statement. It only takes you out of that case and onto the next one which maybe another case, default statement or end of the switch statement as '}'.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, the first example is more clear, you can see each case without barriers. The second example is more difficult because in the same level there are case and break and you can't divide blocks so easy.